# Passing an existing UIWebView to another view for usage?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

I have a bunch of `UIWebViews` in the cells of a `UITableView`. When tapped, I'm opening up a new view and recreating the `UIWebView` in the cell.

Obviously it would be greatly advantageous if I could use the webView instance that already exists, saving the user from opening the web page twice.

However, when I tried passing the webView and adding to its new parent UIView object, the webview seems to have issues resizing itself. Its simply not adjusting its height and width, even though I explicitly adjust it and confirm the new frame size. Is it not possible to resize a webview's frame? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive this is possible. I've done it with custom videoPlayerViews, passed them from a collectionViewCell to a viewController.

Some ideas:

Make sure that you remove the webView from its original superview before adding it as a subview of its new superview.

Make sure your autoResizingMask and constraints are set up properly with respect to the new superview, and destroyed with respect to the original superview.

Comment: I gave your suggestions a try but to no avail. I'm not using any autoResizing also. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code for webview setup, and the exchange of super views? Perhaps some screenshots?